# What's the "Final Memory" meaning in the end of a build process

Tags: netbeans, ant

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD SUCCESS
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 5.219s
Finished at: Fri Feb 03 09:41:10 WET 2017
Final Memory: 21M/204M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What's the meaning of the `21M` and the `204M`?

Comment: That's an output of `Ant` which NetBeans uses as its build tool. It's not NetBeans specific